# Integrating ros to an existing qt application

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, ros

I have a QML, OpenCV application on qt5 which uses qmake and has a .pro file. I want to add publishers/subscribers to my qt project to publish video stream and instructions etc. I tried to use catkin_create_qt_pkg command to create a template and transfer my project to the template but there were numerous problems which made me question my approach. The ros-qt template uses Cmakelist and .ui instead of qml. So, I will need to change some things to integrate them.

First, is it possible to use ros with qmake and .pro instead of cmake. It would be easier to add just ros publishers and listeners to my existing application than changing the entire QML application. If not, how do I convert qmake and .pro to cmake and Cmakelist.txt (assuming that I can use QML with ros). Also, although it doesn't sound well, is it possible to use .pro for qt and Cmakelist.txt for ros in the same package?

Second, is it safe to use qt5 and qml with ros? The ros_qt app template uses qt4, not qt5. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates) is the app template.

Comment: As I remember all the ROS GUI utilities written with Qt, rqt etc. so you can check the source to get an idea how to archive your target.